# NoSuchMethodError when attempting to convert Java iterator to Scala iterator

Tags: scala, nosuchmethoderror

I'm am trying to iterate over the files in a directory in Scala and then run `foreach` on the result. However, when I try to do this I keep getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.convert.Decorators$AsScala scala.jdk.CollectionConverters$.asScalaIteratorConverter(java.util.Iterator)'`

Here are by build.sbt and code snippet trying to perform the conversion.

**build.sbt**

```
name := "patient-profile-generation"
version := "0.0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
  scalapb.gen() -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "scalapb"
)


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value,
  
  "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion % "protobuf",

  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.4.0",

)

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-feature")
```

**Code calling `asScala`**

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file

class MyClass(
    elementsDirectoryString: String = "",
    saveDirectory: String = ""
) {
  private val elementsDirectory = file.Paths.get(elementsDirectoryString)
  private var directoryStream: Option[DirectoryStream[file.Path]] = None

  if (Files.exists(elementsDirectory) && Files.isDirectory(elementsDirectory)) {
    directoryStream = Some(
      Files.newDirectoryStream(
        elementsDirectory,
        (p: file.Path) => Files.isRegularFile(p) /* Exclude directories */
      )
    )
  }

  private val fileListIterator: Iterator[file.Path] = directoryStream match {
    case Some(value) =>
      value
        .iterator()
        .asScala /* Convert from Java iterator to Scala Iterator */
    case None => Iterator[file.Path]()
  }
// ... remainder of my code
```

Can anyone tell me why I see this error when I run with Scala 2.12 but not 2.13? I need to use 2.12 as I will eventually need to integrate with Spark and from what I've seen 2.13 isn't yet officially supported.

Comment: That's an odd thing. `import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._` is not in 2.12. Are you compiling it against 2.13 and trying to run on 2.12? That would explain the NoSuchMethodException. You are not running your code in SBT are you?

Comment: There is also a great library for handling files: https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files

Comment: Thanks @pedrofurla. I just realized that I'm compiling against 2.12 but the version of Scala on my computer when I try to run my JAR is 2.13. Though I'm not sure why this would be an issue.

Comment: I downloaded the Scala 2.12.2 binary and then was able to run the code in the JAR without issue.

Answer (score 4):

Because 2.12 and 2.13 are not compatible in that case (there is no backward compatibility).

In 2.12 you should use

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
```

not

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
```